# Best way to visually compare an individual's value to multiple subgroup means in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

For an individual feedback sheet generated by a Shiny App in R I would like to visually compare an individual's value in variable X to the mean of the whole group, the mean of people of the same age and the mean of people playing the same sports. I was considering making a barplot with four bars for each value and since I keep reading ggplot2 is neat for making plots tried to figure out how to do it in ggplot2. However when trying to implement this idea the factor on the x axis would conceptually be the subsets of the dataset and since the subsets are build from different variables and one individual can be in more than one subset I absolutely can't seem to wrap my head around how to actually feed that into any barplot synthax I found. I wondered if your could just make a list along the lines of c(your_value, mean(group), mean(age_subset), mean(sports_subset)) but I didn't find if that was possible also first making a list or even a second dataframe seems kinda messy to me - isn't there an easier and more elegant way to do something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I start with arbitrary numbers (equivalent to the list you considered starting with). The code might give you an idea how to make a general function of the kind you're seeking.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

own_result <- 5.4
mean_age <- 5.6
mean_sport <- 4.5
data.frame(group = c("age", "sport"),
       means = c(mean_age, mean_sport)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = means)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = own_result, lty = 2, col = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: What does the  %>% mean? I tried building something from your suggestion but R will complain about that bit

Comment: It is the "pipe" from the `magrittr` package, which is imported by `dplyr`. If you ran `library(dplyr)` first, as in my code, then you should not see an error. Or, run `library(tidyverse)`, which gives you `dplyr`, `ggplot2`, and a bunch of other stuff.

Comment: Okay, I see- thanks. I actually forgot loading dplyr in my own code but since I didn't know what the characters meant I didn't know what to look for.